# Ruby On Rails undefined local variable or method `profile_params' for ProfileController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a controller and a view to modify data/information of a user. Like i want to change the phone number of a user but I do not know how. Below are some photos with my code.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxSvX.png)

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heAmJ.png)

[application_controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APDRV.png)

[app/controllers/profile_controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVGSx.png)

[app/views/profile/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm5fb.png)

Comment: let remove `profile_params` into  `private profile_params`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, please post code as **text**, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Your `profile_controller.rb` has a few errors.

Firstly, rails convention is that controller names are pluralized. So your model is correctly `profile.rb`, but you will want to change the controller to `profiles_controller.rb`.

And that `profiles_controller.rb` should look like this:

```
def edit
  if current_user.update(profile_params)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Profile updated'
  else
    render :index, notice: 'Something went wrong'
  end
end

private

def profile_parmas
  params.require(:user).permit(:phone_number)
end
```

Assuming you are using the Devise gem for your users, it is `current_user`.

The specific error you are seeing is due to having 'profile params' on the same line as 'private'.

UPDATE

Your view needs some changes.

Use

```
<%= form_with model: current_user ...
```

And the phone number is not a password field so you would want

```
<%= form.text_field :phone_number ...
```

Comment: I deleted profile params on the same line as private. now im getting an error which looks like this "param is missing or the value is empty: user" . I am having only one model which is User model who has (email/password_digest/phone_number) . Should i create a new model called profile in order to update my current model user? I am not using devise but i created a function for the current user in application controller.

Comment: I didn't see your view. I will ammend my answer

Comment: You don't need a new model. If you use `Current.user` do you get an error? I'm not sure that's a thing. I would recommend using Devise or alike, however

Comment: Thank you for your time. I solved the issue. the main problem was that private thing and wrote my routes incorectly. now its working. Thank you.